# lucene.net combine multiple filters and no search terms

Tags: full-text-search, lucene, lucene.net

How can I do a Filter across multiple fields in Lucene.Net? On one field I simply do:

```
TermQuery tool = new TermQuery(new Term("Tool", "Nail"));
Filter f = new QueryFilter(tool);
```

If I now wanted to add a nail length to the filter, how can I do that?

Also, I want the user to be a able to do a search with  no search term (i.e. by just choosing a category) how can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're asking two questions...

***Question 1: Adding an additional filter***

Remember, `QueryFilter` accepts *any* query (not just `TermQuery`). Therefore, you can create a `BooleanQuery` of the criteria you wish to filter on.

```
TermQuery toolQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Tool", "Nail"));
TermQuery nailLengthQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("NailLength", "3 inches"));

BooleanQuery filterQuery = new BooleanQuery();
filterQuery.add(toolQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
filterQuery.add(nailLengthQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

Filter f = new QueryFilter(filterQuery);
```

***Question 2: Searching without a search term***

If the user provides no search term, you can search using a `MatchAllDocsQuery` query.